# Group By query for date based on Custom Time Period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm building a `WCF` application for calculating total time spend between in and out time, to fetch data from database I'm using `GROUP BY` clause to group data by date, but I want my day to start & end at 6:00 AM so if anyone leaves at 3 in the morning, it'll be added in the current day only. I'm using the following command query

```
SELECT MIN([Swipedatetime]) AS [Entry]
     , MAX([Swipedatetime]) AS [Exit]
     , [UserID]
  FROM [Database_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name]
 where UserID = '100'
 GROUP 
    BY UserID
     , CAST (Swipedatetime as DATE)
 ORDER 
    BY MIN([Swipedatetime])
```

Also If there is any way by which the difference between the two times can be calculated in the stored procedure only then please mention it, it'll be of great use.

Comment: This makes no sense. If your "day" begins at 6am, then a time of 3am means that the row is considered for the PREVIOUS day, not the "current" day (which is the actual date found in your Swipdatetime column).

Comment: @SMor I think that's the reason I asked if I don't customize my query then day will start at 12 AM and ends at that time only, the reason I asked for help is because I want to start my day at 6 AM

Answer (score 0):

To get only records between 6am and 6pm you can use this:

```
where datepart(hour,[Swipedatetime]) > 6 
and datepart(hour,[Swipedatetime]) <=18
```

For the diff you can use this:

```
select DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([Swipedatetime]), MAX([Swipedatetime]))
```

So full query:

```
    declare @StartDate datetime = dateadd(HH, 6, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
    declare @EndDate datetime = dateadd(day,1,@Startdate)

SELECT MIN([Swipedatetime]) AS [Entry]
     , MAX([Swipedatetime]) AS [Exit]
     , DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([Swipedatetime]), MAX([Swipedatetime])) AS[Diff]
     , [UserID]
  FROM [Database_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name]
 where UserID = '100'
and [Swipedatetime] >= @Startdate
and [Swipedatetime] < @EndDate
 GROUP 
    BY UserID
     , CAST (Swipedatetime as DATE)
 ORDER 
    BY MIN([Swipedatetime])
```

Comment: datepart(hour,[Swipedatetime]) <=18 picks value before 7:00 PM of the same day only, instead of that last time I need is 5:59 AM of the next day

Answer (score 0):

How about deducting 6 hours from the Swipedatetime and grouping by that new value:

`GROUP BY (Swipedatetime - INTERVAL '6 hours')`

(this is postgresql, for sql-server I think you need the function dateadd(hour, -6, Swipedatetime), or something along this line)

Comment: It's `dateadd(hour, -6, Swipedatetime)`, but in the worst case scenario if the entry is at 6 AM then maybe in that case `GROUP BY` clause will fail. For all other cases it'll work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution need only simple `DATEADD` function:

```
SELECT MIN([Swipedatetime]) AS [Entry]
     , MAX([Swipedatetime]) AS [Exit]
     , [UserID]
  FROM [dbo].[Table_Name]
 WHERE UserID = '100'
 GROUP 
    BY UserID
     , CAST (DATEADD(HOUR,6,Swipedatetime) AS DATE)
 ORDER 
    BY MIN([Swipedatetime])
```